# Any way to edit Autoping app?

Tags: applications

I found a free menu bar app ([AutoPing](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autoping/id632347870?mt=12)) that works well at allowing me to keep a visual check on whether my internet connection is up or down (I live in a country with frequent instability in connectivity).

However, I'd like to change the placing of the numeric output to the left, not the right, of the indicator icon, or if necessary get rid of it, because all I really need is the green or red indicator.

[image]

I'm a complete beginner. Anyone know a way to edit such an app in the way I'd like?

I tried opening up package contents, but I don't immediately see what (if anything) can be changed to tweak the app.

p.s., I looked for the developer, but it ends up being an ISP and though I mailed them some days ago I got no reply.

Comment: I just checked your app. The file you want to edit is ' /Applications/autoping.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib'. nib files are Interface Builder files and contain the Graphical interface/layout of an app. Normally you can use Xcode to edit nib files. But it seems the nib file of autoping is compiled and can not be edited. –

Answer (score 1):

You may find [Menu Meters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) from Alex Harper @ Raging Menace more to your liking. It is customizable, in that you can decide what to display or not. I use it on all my macs.

In addition to monitoring network throughput, it can also monitor disk, CPU and RAM. It is also freeware. If you use it, donate to the coder!

Comment: Thanks, but I have many monitors, use Bartender, etc. This is specifically a ping widget that I'd like to use, but adapt, if anyone has the knowledge how

Answer (score 1):

## Geektool

You can setup [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) to run scripts and print the output anywhere on your screen. Here is an example of a script that pings google and says if it can find it or not.

```
if ping -c 1 8.8.4.4 >/dev/null; then    # ping google's dns server (silence the output)
  echo '✅'                              # when we have succes, echo 'online'
else
  echo ''                              # when we failed, echo 'offline'
fi
```

Using GeekTool you can put '✅', or '' anywhere on your screen. The refreshrate can also be set in GeekTool.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to try to edit the app in my question. Added to which, Geektool is a bit old and I try to keep my system and apps more current

Comment: Clear. It is not possible to move menubar applications from the right to the left. Period. You can often (mostly OS X apps only) move them around (command-drag), but only within the right side of the menubar. When you want them to the left you need some kind of hack. And, 'Old' apps are not by definition bad apps ;)

Comment: I guess my original question was not clear. In the image above, the green circle and 109ms are part of the same app. Autoping. I just wanted to tweak the app to do: a) flip the circle to the right of the 109ms; OR b) get rid of the 109ms output altogether. To make an analogy, in CSS it would a simple value change.  But when it comes to apps, I don't know how to do this. Some pointers is what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Aha!. Now I get it. Thanks for the update. I leave the answer for other users. As a hint: You might check the plist files in the preferences folder. Big change the order of appearance is listed there.

Comment: I just checked your app. The file you want to edit is ' /Applications/autoping.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib'. nib files are Interface Builder files and contain the Graphical interface/layout of an app. Normally you can use Xcode to edit nib files. But it seems the nib file of autoping is compiled and can not be edited.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Many thanks for taking the time. Much appreciated.